# std::errc, how to indicate success in retval

Tags: c++, c++14

I would like to write a c++ function like this:

```
#include <system_error>
std::errc f() { return std::errc::success; }
```

But I can't understand how to return a successful value (0 in this case) using std::errc 'enum class' type. The one way i see is to return int:

```
template <typename E>
constexpr typename std::underlying_type<E>::type to_underlying(E e) {
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<E>::type>(e);
}

int f() { is_succ() ? 0 : to_underlying(err); }
```

But it looks ugly for me. Is where a standard way to return a C-oriented success/error code from a function in a std c++ 0x14?

PS. I'm using MS VC 2015 Patch 2.

Comment: Why not just use `int`, and `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: 1972 called..

Comment: Ok. My main goal is to write a c-api wrapper c++ library. i've declared a set of function extern "C" and so on. now i have to return an int from them to idicate an error state (or success). So i have to translate exceptions or internal error codes to somting valuable for C users inside c++ code. I thought that the std::errc was a good choise. Looks like that wasn't a good idea. Now i choose between native int and boost::system::errc types.
PS. Sorry about my bad English :)

Comment: You just need to return default constructed std::error_code instance. Is there is a problem with that?

Comment: `std::from_chars` introduced in c++17 value initialise `std::from_chars_result::ec` (`std::errc`) to indicate success so I guess this can be relied up by the standard? `static_cast<int>(std::errc{}) == 0`.

Comment: Now without success value in enum `std::from_chars` situation looks like worst design ever. Success is signified by out-of-enum value which usually means something went wrong beyond belief.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <system_error>

std::errc f() { return std::errc(); }

int main()
{
    std::errc x = f();
    if (x == std::errc())
    {
        // success
    }
}
```

`std::errc()` (0) is a valid enumeration value even though it does not appear in the enumerator list, which start at 1. It represents success.

For comparison, have a look at [std::to_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars), which returns a

```
struct to_chars_result {
    char* ptr;
    std::errc ec;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You generally don't return a `std::errc` value from a function directly.  Instead, you return a `std::error_code`.  For example, your function would be declared like this:

```
std::error_code f();
```

You then compare the result of that function against the std::errc values.  For example:

```
std::error_code error = f();
if (error == std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory)
{
  // deal with the error
}
```

`std::error_code`is contextually convertible bool.  The way you test if a function succeeded is by using the error code in a boolean expression.  For example:

```
std::error_code error = f();
if (error)
{
  // the function failed...
}
```

To return success from such a function, you return a default initialized `std::error_code`.  For example:

```
std::error_code f()
{
  // do stuff...
  return std::error_code{}; // success!
}
```

This approach works well when you're *consuming* a C-style API.  Your wrapper would construct `std::error_code` objects using the integer values returned by the API and a custom `std::error_category` that defines how to translate those errors into `std::errc` values.

The opposite doesn't work, however.  If you're writing a C wrapper for a C++ library, then you have to do things the C way.  Define an `enum` with your error values and return those values from your C entry points.

Comment: In theory it is good design. But in practice `std::error_code` is 128-bit variable (int + padding + pointer) and in some cases it may be too expensive to return it from function. If errors are not so frequent, price to return error code will be too high, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

One might imagine a quick (and dirty) answer to your question:

```
// default category is std::system_error
inline std::error_code system_error_code_default{};
```

you might make a global default instance of a system error, whose internal value is indeed 0 (zero) and that is a "mark of success". And then you use this to "mean an ok retval"

```
std::error_code very_complex_operation ()  
{
  return {};
   // same as
  // return error_code_success ;
}
```

And then you can check for success upon return

```
    auto errcde = very_complex_operation();
    auto default_category_name = errcde.category().name();

    if (system_error_code_default == errcde) {
      // the sucess 
    }  else {
      // error condition
    }
```

And this will indeed work, and you do not have to "do anything else". 
But. This is all logically happening in the "system" error category aka domain.

```
    // "system"
    auto default_category_name = errcde.category().name();
```

Thus, you are in the domain of "system" errors, here. If this is what you want ok. But I doubt it. Immediately after "playing" with the above you will want to define your own std::error_code system, with your own enumerations, category, messages and the rest. Signalling errors pertinent to your API only.

To understand why just think of the std::error_code usage pattern in the presence of multiple error categories. Understand std namespace does it that way. there are at least three categories in there.

Your users/clients might be writing a C++ app where there might be a dozen or more of different libraries. If you develop your API with your own but standard std::error_code system it will feel "normal" to use. Users will be able and perhaps willing, to integrate your API in their programs.

I hope this answers the question in a bit more comprehensive manner.
If you wish to proceed in the direction of your own error codes (and more) please [proceed here](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-1.html).

Admittedly standard C++ error code based handling appears a bit over-engineered. I might think the key, in understanding it, is to take the point of view of the user of your code or library if you will.

Answer (score -1):

From [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc):

> The scoped enumeration `std::errc` defines the values of portable error conditions that correspond to the POSIX error codes.

`std::errc` constants are for comparing against when you're checking whether some particular error condition occurred (as shown in the example on that page).

Success is not an error condition.

Return an `std::error_code` instead, which may wrap one of these error conditions or, by default, no error condition (i.e. success).

Comment: std::errc f() { return std::errc::success; }
What should I write in the function body to return success status? That was a question.

Comment: Yep, I had to. I had to read an explanation not an answer. Nothing personal, I've accepted the fact that c++ shouldn't return a success value :) Just for me, it looks unpredictable. At least.

Comment: `std::from_chars` returns a value-initialized `errc` on success, so it isn't only used for errors.